# POST Request not supported by Google Server

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, httpcontext, google-authentication

I am getting following error while posting request from my server to google.com:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://accounts.google.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed in C:\...\index.php on line 23

My code is following:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'code'          => '####',
        'client_id'     => '####',
        'client_secret' => '####',
        'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code'
    )
);

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://accounts.google.com', false, $context);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Don`t post credentials :)

Comment: Well, you should contact google here. HTTP/1.0 does not have the 405 error code according to RFC 1945 so the 4xx class applies: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-9.4 - "Guessing" from HTTP/1.1 (which has the 405 code), this is explained here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.6

Comment: Already reported this issue at google. Waiting for their response. Although When I use "fopen" or "curl" it does not give any error but it gives empty response.

Answer (score 0):

the method you have chosen is 'PUT' and not 'POST'. if you want to send request as POST then change

> 'method'  => 'PUT'

to

> 'method'  => 'POST'

Comment: I checked with both PUT and POST but same thing happened. For GET its giving Error 400.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you get here is a response code (405) and it is within the error class (400 to 499 or also written as *4xx*).

So the server reports back to you an error on the protocol level. The protocol used is named as well: HTTP, more specifically HTTP/1.0.

HTTP/1.0 including the status codes are outlined in RFC1945:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945

The problem here is that the code 405 (as the concrete number) is not defined. So the docs fall back to the general description of [4xx for error codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-9.4).

HTTP/1.1 is outlined in RFC2616:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

It has [the 405 error code details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.6) however, as the response headers in your code example show:

```
// ...
$result = file_get_contents('http://accounts.google.com', false, $context);

var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0] => string(31) "HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed"
  [1] => string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  [2] => string(19) "Content-Length: 958"
  [3] => string(35) "Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2013 12:03:09 GMT"
  [4] => string(15) "Server: GFE/2.0"
  [5] => string(27) "Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic"
}
```

The required response listing shows another protocol violation as the required Allow header is not part of the response. It would have shown which methods are allowed.

So all you can do is to try if common HTTP methods work instead of PUT, you might be looking for POST. Let's run the example with POST, but no luck:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://accounts.google.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

I suggest you contact Google (the vendor of that online service you send HTTP requests to) and ask about the technical specification you need to match for the request you had in mind. For debugging purposes I suggest you read about PHP's special [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/http_response_header) variable, I have some example code and explanation as well as some hints on error handling with [PHP's HTTP Wrapper](http://php.net/wrappers.http) in:

- [HEAD first with PHP Streams (Sep 2011; by hakre)](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the wrong URI, (which is why you get no allowed methods header). Access tokens are retrieved via https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token "https" is required.

Unrelated: Your postdata is missing the required "redirect_uri".

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late, hope it helps someone else like me.

There are two issues. First of all an access token cannot be generated with `client_secret`. So to have a successful request `client_secret` must be included.

Secondly google wants to identify the `client_id`, so it should also be a part of `POST` parameters.

The correct parameters for generating access tokens should be like

```
$opts = array(
'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata,
    'client_id' => '######################',
    'client_secret' => '##########################'
 )
)
```