# Curl and Google Forms

Tags: php, curl, google-forms

I am making the PHP script that will automatically fill Google Forms document. I am doing with Curl.However, there problems with correctness of work this script

```
$text="forTestOnly";
if( $curl = curl_init() ){
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'SOME_URL');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
  if( $html = curl_exec($curl) ){
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'SOME_URL');
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
     curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"entry.867207060=$text&submit=ok");
     $out = curl_exec($curl);
     echo $out;
  }
  curl_close($curl);
 }
```

It gives such error:**"HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed"**. What is the problem?

With regards

[Link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1bJXxSXzIkm7NtDCZXE4J3VF5UugVm4B_qTFuGFp1bKE/viewform)

---

**EDIT:**

Problem was not in the settings of **Curl**(POST) but the **URL** I provided was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Google may have disallowed the POST method for Google Forms, probably as a precaution against, erm, automated requests.

See

[POST Request not supported by Google Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565191/post-request-not-supported-by-google-server)

for a general explanation of why you're being served the Error message, or better still

[cURL not fetching the expected POST response - error 405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307079/curl-not-fetching-the-expected-post-response-error-405)

for a possible solution - see the uprated answer's suggested

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( array(...) ));
```

method, which may or may not allow you to bypass Google's anti-automation measures.

Comment: ok, I also thought it prevention from automated requests is the case.